# How do I calculate all password possibilities when the length is fixed?

Tags: calculus

I have the following password characteristics:

- Length: 8 characters
- Letters: English only, a-z, A-Z
- Numbers: 0-9

Example of a valid password: Ms9Sx0A1

The correct way of calculating the above but with a length of **up to** 8 characters is: 62^8, is that correct?

How does this calculation changes when I know the password length is exactly 8 characters?

Comment: No, that's the number of passwords with length exactly $8$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum up the possible number of passwords of length $1,2,3,\dots,8$. This gives us the number of possible passwords **up to** 8 characters long as

$$\sum_{i = 1}^8{62^i}$$

If the password is exactly 8 characters long, then there are indeed $62^8$ possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

For a simpler expression, consider that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^k=\frac{x^{n+1}-x}{x-1}$$ so in this particular case the number of passwords with length up to $8$ 
is $$\frac{62^9-62}{61}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Well you can choose every character on $62$ ways thus it is $62^8$,if it was upto $8$ characters it would be $62^8+62^7+62^6+62^5+62^4+62^3+62^2+63$